# Has the Worker Role WADLogsTable PartitionKey format changed?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-diagnostics

I have a number of Cloud Services deployed in Azure that contain worker roles.

I have enabled diagnostics on all of them using the Powershell command:
`Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension`

Normally I can write an efficient query to read the last x minutes of logs by following the advice given here:

http://gauravmantri.com/2012/02/17/effective-way-of-fetching-diagnostics-data-from-windows-azure-diagnostics-table-hint-use-partitionkey/

e.g. `PartitionKey gt '0636032460000000000'`

This works nicely because the PartitionKey of the table is normally the number of ticks of the minute in which the log message was recorded. e.g. 0636032460000000000 -> 4/07/2016 4:20:00 PM

However on some of my deployments, the PartitionKey has become prepended with a number e.g. 0000000000000000001___0636032460000000000

Does anyone know why the PartitionKey has this prefix, what the prefix means and when it is applied? Is there any way to stop that prefix from being added?

With this change in PartitionKey format is there still an efficient way to query for logs using the PartitionKey?
I'm concerned that if 0000000000000000002 is suddenly prepended I could end up with an invalid query or incorrect results.

I could also use the Timestamp property value in a query e.g. `Timestamp ge datetime'2016-08-15T22:57:29.132Z'` but I believe this will cause a full table scan every time I run the query, making the query become slower and slower as the table grows larger, is that assumption correct?

Cheers.

Comment: Could the prefix be the machine number in a load balanced set?

Comment: I'm not sure, how would I check if a load balanced set is being used by my worker?

Comment: Did you scale up to multiple workers? Cloud Services automatically use load balancers

Comment: Yes autoscailing is configured - could that explain it?

Comment: With autoscaling you can have multiple machines each logging to the table. To distinguish between each machine, a prefix is applied (this can also be seen in the Portal, each machine has a number)